# Display column values using if statement in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, comparison-operators

I wonder why the condition for tuition fee repeats twice? What i want is to retrieve data from database.and in my view is the list of two rows in different ul-list that corresponds the condition of 3 if staments.

```
         ///table Need
            id          scholar_need
            1           Tuition Fee
            2           Books

        public view(){
            $needs = Need::all();
        return view(view,compact('needs));
        }

    @foreach($needs as $need)

if($need->scholar_need = 'Tuition Fee'){
<label class="col-lg-3">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Tuition Fee</li>
<ul>                                 
<li>Tuition</li>
<li>Miscellaneous</li>
<li>Projects</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</label>
}
elseif($need->scholar_need = 'Books'){
<label class="col-lg-3">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Books</li>
<ul>                                 
<li>NoteBooks</li>
<li>Books</li>
<li>Magazines</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</label>
}
elseif($need->scholar_need = 'Clothing'){
<label class="col-lg-3">
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Clothing</li>
<ul>                                 
<li>Uniform</li>
<li>Personal</li>
<li>P.E.</li>
</ul>
</ul>
</label>
}

    @endforeach
```

This is the output of my code.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Tuition Fee</li>
<ul>                                 
<li>Tuition</li>
<li>Miscellaneous</li>
<li>Projects</li>
</ul>
</ul>

<ul class="list-unstyled">
<li>Tuition Fee</li>
<ul>                                 
<li>Tuition</li>
<li>Miscellaneous</li>
<li>Projects</li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well you have a foreach, maybe there is two element in your array `needs`...

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings in PHP, you need `==` (or even `===`, if both have to be the same type of it is security sensitive, [the PHP docs cover the difference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)).

```
if($need->scholar_need == 'Tuition Fee'){
```

The same needs to be done for all other comparisons.

The reason that you saw Tuition Fee twice is that with one `=`, `$need->scholar_need` was being set to the value `'Tuition Fee'`; the operation of which is always `true`. As such, the condition was being found true for the first if() statement each time (i.e. 'Tuition Fee' here).